# Why do my images seem to be in the format of Bgra instead of Argb?

Tags: c#, image-processing, lockbits

So, I am very confused over a quick test that I just ran.  I am doing some image processing in C#.  Get/SetPixel() have proven to be too slow, so I am using LockBits to get at the raw data.

However, I seem to have hit a situation which I can't figure out.  While scanning the image, it seems that each pixel is laid out as Bgra, that is, blue byte, green byte, red byte, and alpha, in that order.  I was under the impression that they would be laid out in Argb order.  here is a sample of the code that I am using.

```
BitmapData baseData =
    m_baseImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), m_baseImage.Size), 
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Bitmap test = new Bitmap(m_baseImage.Width, m_baseImage.Height);           

byte* ptr = (byte*)baseData.Scan0;
for (int y = 0; y < m_baseImage.Height; ++y)
{                              
    for (int x = 0; x < m_baseImage.Width; ++x)
    {
        // this works, image is copied correctly
        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(*(ptr + 3), *(ptr + 2), *(ptr + 1), *ptr);
        // below does not work!  Bytes are reversed.
        //Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(*ptr, *(ptr + 1), *(ptr + 2), *(ptr + 3));

        test.SetPixel(x, y, c1);
        ptr += 4;
    }             
}

m_baseImage.UnlockBits(baseData);
pictureBox1.Image = m_baseImage;
pictureBox2.Image = test;
```

The first line which grabs the color of the base image works, the second does not.  I am pretty sure that I am missing something very obvious here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only are the colors reversed BGRA, but the rows are reversed as well - the bottom of the image is the first in memory.  It's just the way Windows has always worked.

The little-endian explanation seems obvious, but I don't think it's the truth.  If you look at the definition of [COLORREF in the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449(VS.85).aspx), you'll notice that Red is the low order byte and Blue is the higher order; if you stored this as a single integer value, it would be RGB0.

Comment: You are right.  It is a Windows thing, not due to the endianness of the CPU.

Answer (score 7):

ARGB refers to the byte order in words fetched as words. If you fetch the bytes one at a time, you'll receive em low to hi as IBM PC's are [little-endian](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~Verts/cs32/endian.html)